# Access XP database asking users to register a username and initials, not set to do this

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

i apologise if the answer to this question is listed somewhere but i can't seem to find it!
I have an Access XP database in shared use by about 70 people, on some PC's the database asks for a Username and Initials when opened. The database has not been set to do this and it only happens on a small number of PC's.
The next time the user tries to get into the database it comes up with an error explaining that the current person does not have XP installed (this is in the XP window when it opens) or isn't registered. From what i gather from various pages on google this could be down to the security settings on the PC but i'm not sure. Apologies if this is a fairly vague question, i can try give more details if asked. I hope someone can help!
Kris

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it's actually MS Office. When you've installed Office, the first app you run will ask for a name and initials; once that's done once I don't think it asks again.

When you say 'in the XP window' what are you referring to? Is XP running in a VPC or something?

If Office licenced on all these machines?